# How to print to an oldish HP Designjet 600 with Windows 7 and/or Linux?

Tags: windows-7, linux, drivers, printer

The HP DesignJet 600 is an older 'plotter' (really a large Inkjet printer) and we have one that's still working great.

We're in the process of upgrading workstations to new PCs running Windows7 64bit, and HP [does not support](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&objectID=c00852513&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN) that printer any more since Vista. I thought we could attach it to a Linux system and go from there but it seem [it's not supported there](http://www.openprinting.org/printers) either and the HPLIP project [won't help](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/designjet/hp_designjet_600.html) too.

AFAIK, attaching to a Windows XP system will let that XP print but I won't be able to share the printer and use it from the networked Windows7 given the lack of drivers.

My current option seem to be 'printing' to pdf, moving the file on a Windows XP, and manually print it using Adobe Reader.

Is there any better way to accomplish printing from the Windows 7 systems? Or at least to automatize the print to pdf > move file > print it process?

Comment: Have you tried using Windows XP mode or another type of virtualization?

Comment: @molgar I'm no Windows expert but AFAIK the 'windows xp mode' is only for apps and not for drivers. If it isn't so, where should I look?

Comment: I am no expert, I was just thinking out loud, so you may be right. I guess you already tried using vista x64 drivers.